# Configuring vxlan unicast in linux

Tags: linux, linux-networking, linux-kernel

I want to try vxlan unicast and configured following configurations in Fedora 23

VM1(enp0s8) ========= (enp0s8)VM2

```
ip address add 100.1.1.1/24 dev enp0s8
ifconfig enp0s8 up
ip link add name vxlan42 type vxlan id 42 dev enp0s8 remote 50.1.1.2 local 50.1.1.1 dstport 4789
ip address add 50.1.1.1/24 dev vxlan42
ip link set up vxlan42

ip address add 100.1.1.2/24 dev enp0s8
ifconfig enp0s8 up
ip link add name vxlan42 type vxlan id 42 dev enp0s8 remote 50.1.1.1 local 50.1.1.2 dstport 4789
ip address add 50.1.1.2/24 dev vxlan42
ip link set up vxlan42
```

When I ping 50.1.1.1 from VM2, ARP packets received on VM1 are not vxlan tagged as a result PING is not working.

Is there anything wrong with my configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

The remote IP should be 100.1.1.1/100.1.1.2. This should work:

```
ip address add 100.1.1.1/24 dev enp0s8
ifconfig enp0s8 up
ip link add name vxlan42 type vxlan id 42 dev enp0s8 remote 100.1.1.2 local 100.1.1.1 dstport 4789
ip address add 50.1.1.1/24 dev vxlan42
ip link set up vxlan42

ip address add 100.1.1.2/24 dev enp0s8
ifconfig enp0s8 up
ip link add name vxlan42 type vxlan id 42 dev enp0s8 remote 100.1.1.1 local 100.1.1.2 dstport 4789
ip address add 50.1.1.2/24 dev vxlan42
ip link set up vxlan42
```